Why does a DALI relay module require external power but KNX does not?
DALI relay modules have L/N/PE inputs. KNX relay modules do not, and trigger relays on bus power alone. Given that in both cases the bus power is sufficient to flip a bistable relay, why do DALI relay modules insist on using external power? What purpose does this serve? (Yes, DALI line itself has enough power to flip a bistable relay.)

They are two completely different standards for different applications and have different specifications which defines what is possible and what isn't.
DALI requires a power supply to run the isolated data communications with for example optoisolators, and no more than 2mA can be consumed per DALI device, voltage being 12-22V. Thus, a DALI device is not allowed to suck much power. It's simply a powered current loop for data transfer. The current is not available during data transfer, so on a busy bus, there might be not enough idle time to be able to harvest the power for driving latching relays.
KNX bus is basically similar to power lines with data communications superimposed on it. There is 10mA always available even if data is communicated on bus so it can be harvested into a capacitor to drive latching relays.

It's really nice to read such a well-written, easy-to-understand answer which boils a lot of complex standards differences into such a clear explanation.

Relay modules come under part 208 Switching Function which are part of the Control Gear spec, and most Control Gear are not bus powered, as opposed to Control Devices (300 series) such as button panels, sensors etc which are normally bus powered. However, it is allowed to have bus powered Control Gear, in which case the maximum current consumption when not transmitting is theoretically 250mA but is needed to be less so that it doesn't put a LOW on the bus. As long as the gear is marked with the consumption and the PSU can cope with that, it is allowed.

It is allowed to have DALI relay modules which are bus powered, so it is just a product design choice as to whether to use that as the power source for the relay coil or to use the mains inputs and a step down PSU circuit. Here's a list of certified relay modules which are bus powered, 23 at time of writing. You can see the current consumption by clicking on any of these, and see that it is more than the 2.0mA allowed for non bus powered devices. This is allowed in the standard as long as the device declares what it draws when not transmitting and it is below 250mA and the chosen bus power supply does not drop it's voltage below 12.0V for the full quiescent current consumption of the bus.
